# Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices' after run expo run:android

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, expo

I got this error when I run expo run:android:

> Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'.
> com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Use JsonReader.setLenient(true) to accept malformed JSON at line 1 column 4 path

Here is my google-services.json

```
{
  "project_info": {
    "project_number": "1006344582861",
    "firebase_url": "https://petingdate.firebaseio.com",
    "project_id": "petingdate",
    "storage_bucket": "petingdate.appspot.com"
  },
  "client": [
    {
      "client_info": {
        "mobilesdk_app_id": "1:1006344582861:android:b5675e2f2b8bc16ff75b84",
        "android_client_info": {
          "package_name": "host.exp.exponent.android"
        }
      },
      "oauth_client": [
        {
          "client_id": "1006344582861-nj9ivgr3gosg8ucbokohsnama3mdq9lv.apps.googleusercontent.com",
          "client_type": 1,
          "android_info": {
            "package_name": "host.exp.exponent.android",
            "certificate_hash": "e169c1b4bad556732a5160add50b2271dbd15409"
          }
        }
      ],
      "api_key": [
        {
          "current_key": "AIzaSyCn1yyzhe6WAWhipzp1S7snQvxFf9hYND8"
        }
      ],
      "services": {
        "appinvite_service": {
          "other_platform_oauth_client": [
            {
              "client_id": "1006344582861-favl7llics7gkb9dvgped0l563e0lg7e.apps.googleusercontent.com",
              "client_type": 3
            },
            {
              "client_id": "1006344582861-a9eq9kdad4leab41lmm5112ilq7dgo5q.apps.googleusercontent.com",
              "client_type": 2,
              "ios_info": {
                "bundle_id": "host.exp.exponent.peting"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "client_info": {
        "mobilesdk_app_id": "1:1006344582861:android:bf5a1c74f85e6c04f75b84",
        "android_client_info": {
          "package_name": "host.exp.exponent.peting"
        }
      },
      "oauth_client": [],
      "api_key": [
        {
          "current_key": "AIzaSyCn1yyzhe6WAWhipzp1S7snQvxFf9hYND8"
        }
      ],
      "services": {
        "appinvite_service": {
          "other_platform_oauth_client": [
            {
              "client_id": "1006344582861-favl7llics7gkb9dvgped0l563e0lg7e.apps.googleusercontent.com",
              "client_type": 3
            },
            {
              "client_id": "1006344582861-a9eq9kdad4leab41lmm5112ilq7dgo5q.apps.googleusercontent.com",
              "client_type": 2,
              "ios_info": {
                "bundle_id": "host.exp.exponent.peting"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "configuration_version": "1"
}
```

How can I fix this? I use gradle 7.6, opendjdk 11